# How to include one handlebar js file into another?

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I am new to handlebar tempting with Nodejs. I want to include 2 handlebar files into one. So after a little googling I tried this

**layout.hbs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/bootstrap.css' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/base.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    {{> header}}
    {{{body}}}
    {{> footer}}
  </body>
</html>
```

**heaeder.hbs**

```
<p>I am header</p>
```

**footer.hbs**

```
<p>I am footer</p>
```

and my folder structure is

views
- layout.hbs
- header.hbs
- footer.hbs

But this doesnt work I get this error

```
Error
   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\SVN HOME 2\YASSER\One-Bitbucket\node_modules\hbs\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\exception.js:29:23)
   at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
   at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
   at require (module.js:384:17)
   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\SVN HOME 2\YASSER\One-Bitbucket\node_modules\hbs\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\base.js:3:17)
   at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
   at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
   at require (module.js:384:17)
   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\SVN HOME 2\YASSER\One-Bitbucket\node_modules\hbs\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars.runtime.js:3:12)
   at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
```

Any idea on how this works ?

Comment: I need to go to bed right now, but from the stack trace, it looks like you're using Handlebars.js. The [docs](http://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html) might be of help. You apparently need to register the partial before you can use it. (I guess you would load the partial template from the template file?) The project also [explicitly states](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js#differences-between-handlebarsjs-and-mustache) that how it handles partials isn't exactly in line with the mustache definition.

Comment: As @jpmc26 said,  You need to register the two templates as partials, and then use them into the main template.

Comment: @jpmc26 yea I am using handlebar js